# MemoryError in Jupyter but not in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, out-of-memory, centos7

I'm running

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
```

with plenty of memory

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G        3.3G        104G        879M         17G        120G
```

64 bit Anaconda https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh

I have set max_buffer_size to 64GB in both jupyter_notebook_config.json and
jupyter_notebook_config.py, and just to make sure specify it on the command line:

`jupyter notebook --certfile=ssl/mycert.perm --keyfile ssl/mykey.key --no-browser --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=64000000000`

And also

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
1
```

I run a simple memory allocation snippet:

```py
    size = int(6e9)
    chunk = size * ['r']
    print (chunk.__sizeof__()/1e9)
```

as a standalone .py file and it works:

```
python ../readgzip.py
48.00000004
```

happily reporting that it allocated 48GB for my list.

However, the same code in a jupyter notebook only works up to 7.76GB:

```py
    size = int(9.7e8)
    chunk = size * ['r']
    print (chunk.__sizeof__()/1e9)
7.76000004
```

and fails after increase the array size from 9.7e8 to 9.75e8

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12328/3436837519.py in <module>
      1 size = int(9.75e8)
----> 2 chunk = size * ['r']
      3 print (chunk.__sizeof__()/1e9)

MemoryError:
```

Also, on my home Windows11 machine with 64GB of memory I can easily run the code above and allocate 32GB of memory.

Seems like, I'm missing something about the Jupyter setup on Linux

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux (and possibly other OSs, but I'm not sure), `MemoryError` doesn't mean that the machine's memory has exhausted (in which case [OOM killer](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/linux-out-of-memory-killer/) would usually be invoked), but rather that the process has reached a limit (A.K.A [ulimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html), obsolete) over which the kernel is not willing to allocate it with additional memory.

You can use python's [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html) library to check the current process's limits (and possibly set them, having sufficient permissions). Here's an example:

```
$ prlimit --as
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION              SOFT      HARD UNITS
AS       address space limit unlimited unlimited bytes
$ prlimit --pid=$$ --as=$((1024*1024*20)):
prlimit --as
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION             SOFT      HARD UNITS
AS       address space limit 20971520 unlimited bytes
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import resource
>>> resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
(20971520, -1)
>>> longstr = "r" * 1024*1024*10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> longstr = "r" * 1024*1024*3
>>> resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (1024*1024*30, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
>>> resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
(31457280, -1)
>>> longstr = "r" * 1024*1024*10
>>> len(longstr)
10485760
>>>
```

Increasing Jupyter-Notebook's limits should be done from outside the process itself, as it is generally not recommended running python processes with superuser privileges.

Read more about linux's [prlimit(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html) utility and the [getrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) system call.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran prlimit --pid 9020 --as=unlimited as a root, problem solved!